# Converter data PHP para salvar no banco Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, data

Preciso receber uma data usando o datapicker como dd/mm/yyyy e mudar para formato aceito no banco (mysql).

tenho os metodos acessores (Getter e Setter) neles apliquei essa função date e o strstring para converter:

```
function setDatavenc($datavenc) {
    $this->datavenc = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($datavenc));
}
```

.

```
function getDatavenc() {
    return date('d/m/Y', strtotime($this->datavenc));
}
```

Porém ao salvar no banco salva `0000-00-00`
E ao fazer a consulta retorna: `01/01/1970`.

Já procurei muito inclusive algumas forma aqui no stackoverflow e nenhuma funcionou.

Comment: Coloque o código (SQL) de como vc grava a data

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO gasto (datavenc, dataentrada)"
                    . " VALUES(:datavenc, :dataentrada)";

Comment: vc passa da ta no formato `d/m/Y` ou `Y-m-d`?

Comment: Passo via input type="text" usando o datapicker como `d/m/Y` 
Preciso que chegue ao banco no formato `Y-m-d` e depois fazer a recuperação para  exibir no input como `d/m/Y'

Answer (score 1):

A função date do PHP funciona da seguinte forma:

> string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp ] )

O formato você pode inserir da maneira que necessita, utilizando está  [TABELA](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) , da página da documentação do PHP.
No seu caso como necessita do formato **0000-00-00** o código ficaria assim:

```
function setDatavenc($datavenc) {
    $this->datavenc = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datavenc));
}
```

Comment: Continua salvando zerado: 0000-00-00

Comment: @JB_ Verifica como está chegando o valor da sua variável **$datavenc**

Comment: Quando contem valor: "2018-09-05", inserido manualmente no banco, quando zerado assim: "-0001-11-30"